# ContentProvider insert isn't inserting data to SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, sqlite

I'm inserting data to a SQLiteDatabase via a ContentProvider. My line of code:

```
Uri mNewUri = getContentResolver().insert(MY_URI, values);
```

values is a ContentValues variable that I've populated with data via various calls to the put method. In the debugger, I see that the insert method returns a valid Uri into mNewUri. However, when I try to display data, I get no data back. When I go to the command line and try:

```
cmd> adb -e shell
cmd> sqlite3 /data/data/com.MyProject.project/databases/db-name.db
sqlite> select * from MyInfo_tbl;
```

(MyInfo_tbl is the table in my database class) But I see no results in the table. The insert method in my ContentProvider is:

```
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
    if (uriType != ALLDATA) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid URI for insert");
    }
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = mDB.getWritableDatabase();
    try {
        long newID = sqlDB.insertOrThrow(TABLE_BASEPATH,
                null, values);
        if (newID > 0) {
            Uri newUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, newID);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            return newUri;
        } else {
            throw new SQLException("Failed to insert row into " + uri);
        }
    } catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Ignoring constraint failure.");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Does anyone know why this would be or where I could start looking to solve this problem? Thanks!

PS I've also tried to insert data to the database by calling a db.execSQL line in the onCreate method of my database provider. This also does not insert any data.

Comment: Are `MyInfo_tbl` and `TABLE_BASEPATH` the same thing?

Comment: Yes, they are the same thing.

Comment: Did you try to query the provider for the `Uri` that the method insert returned?

Comment: The line ContentUris.withAppendedId returns content://com.MyProject.project.MyProvider/MyInfo_tbl/1116 if I follow the code in the debugger. See above for a PS

Comment: The `insert` method looks ok but something seems strange. Do you use a column with `autoincrement` in the `TABLE_BASEPATH` table? Do you already have `1115` values in the table? Also, previously I was referring to check the entry using the `query` method of the `ContentProvider`.

Comment: Yes, there's an autoincrement column in the table. There shouldn't be anything in the table, since I delete everything from the table before I do the insert. If I check the query method of the ContentProvider after the insert, I get a Cursor with a value of android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@412afcb8. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: I'm starting to think something else is wrong here. If I do a query right after the insert and use a cursor to move through the result set, I do get one record, which is right. But it's not displaying later on down the line. I have to look at this again, but it's late on Friday. Monday is another day, but if anyone has any idea why the sqlite command wasn't returning data, I'd love to hear it. Thanks and TGIF!

Comment: If the query method returns a Cursor with the data you just inserted then the provider is ok. So look how exactly do you use the `Cursor` with data.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind not inserting data in database will be either your table creation query will not be executed successfully due some missing commas or some mistake or there will be some problem in uri.